# postgresql self-join query condition not to return repeat results

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have this simplified query:

```
SELECT a.p_key, b.p_key
FROM test AS a, test AS b       
WHERE 
a.p_key != b.p_key -- skip self
AND a.p_key < b.p_key -- symmetry breaker
-- missing extra condition to skip previously fetched results
```

This is the returned data set. The * marks already 'retrieved' b.p_keys:

```
a.p_key p.b_key
1   2
1   3

2   3* (already linked to a.p_key = 1)
2   4

3   4* (already linked to a.p_key = 2)
3   5
```

I have done much research and experimentation but can't seem to reach the result I need:

I want to exclude b.p_keys that have already been retrieved previously, so my actual result set should look like this:

```
a.p_key p.b_key
1   2
1   3

2   4

3   5
```

Comment: You oversimplified. And: `p_key != b_key`

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unclear on the exact purpose of this code, but you can put adjacent pairs in a row using `lead()`:

```
select p_key, lead(p_key) over (order by p_key) as next_p_key
from test;
```

This seems to do what you want, although you might want to filter out the last row with `NULL`:

```
select p_key, next_p_key
from (select p_key, lead(p_key) over (order by p_key) as next_p_key
      from test
     ) t
where next_p_key is not null
```

Comment: the full query actually has some extra conditions related to distance to get points within certain radius of each other, but i do not want previously retrieved points to be fetched again...i simplified the query so it focuses on what's needed

Comment: This is the full query, how would the above apply to it on the join level? (still havent fiddled with it): SELECT a.p_key, a."Lat",a."Lon", b.p_key, b."DID",b."Lat",b."Lon",b.timestamp,b.st_setsrid   
FROM location_signals_test2 as a, location_signals_test2 as b   
WHERE ST_DWITHIN (a.st_setsrid, b.st_setsrid, 100, false)   
AND 
a.p_key != b.p_key 
AND a.p_key < b.p_key

Comment: @roynaufal . . . This answers the question that you asked (at least I think it does).  If you have another question, then you should ask it as a *new* question, not in a comment.

Comment: i was able to work with your reply on a single table, but not as joined results, is it possible you can elaborate your reply to have the join as well?

Comment: @roynaufal . . . `lead()` works on joined results.  You can encapsulate the `join`in a CTE.  However, the point is that you can replace the self-join with `lead()` as you asked this question.  You seem to have asked the wrong question, though, so you should ask another one with more detailed information about what you really need.  This question has been answered.